# Django API throwing a 403 error when called from Azure Functions

Tags: python, django, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-application-insights

I have an instance of Azure Functions which is calling a particular endpoint of a Django API. The Django API doesn't need any authentication and I have used the `@csrf_exempt` annotator in the views.py file. It's a POST request which takes request parameters from the URL. When I call the end-point from Postman, it works fine but when the Azure Functions is making a HTTP Post call, the API throws a 403 Forbidden error. There is no explicit 403 error that is coded in the Django API. Logs on AppInsights suggest that `log.py line 228` is throwing the error. From what I understand, the relevant log.py file is present in `django/utils/log.py`

I am not able to figure out why there is a 403 error from the API. Any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 0):

First at all, I need your Azure function code. Please edit your question and mention that to me.

What I can see now is probably the `CORS` problem. The problem with log.py is negligible. If there was a problem with django itself, it would return 500 errors instead of 403.

[django cors library](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) will help you.

If it wasn't a CORS problem, please log in more detail and update the questions.

- [Django logging doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/)
- [Tutorial post](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-logging-right-way/)

I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: What part of the Azure functions code would you like to see? I will update my question after trying the CORS library that you mentioned.

Comment: @Shanky the part that calls `django API`. And headers of the azure request, if you can get. I recommend this [library](https://github.com/Rhumbix/django-request-logging) for request logging